# What is the difference/function of these CSS selectors?

Tags: html, css

I was just exposed to these, and couldn't find anything else on Google to explain their exact mechanics -- they seem very interesting and potentially useful, however, so here is my CSS:

```
ul[id*="mainSecMenu"]{
    height:70px;
    width:91.6%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
}

li[class="secMenu_link"]{ /*note this used to be class*="secMenu_link", but it prevented CSS cascade from .activeLink */
    display:inline-block;
    height:12px;
    padding:7px;
    background:#f4f4f4;
    border:2px solid #555;
    border-radius:2px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.activeLink {
    display:inline-block;
    height:12px;
    padding:7px;
    background:#f36459;
    border:2px solid #f36459;
    color:#444;
    border-radius:2px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="mainSecMenu_marketing">
    <li class="secMenu_link">MATERIALS BY PRODUCT</li>
    <li class="secMenu_link activeLink">MATERIALS BY TYPE</li>
    <li class="secMenu_link">TRADESHOW &amp; DEMO TOOLS</li>
    <li class="secMenu_link">BRAND GUIDELINES &amp; LOGOS</li>
    <li class="secMenu_link">MATERIAL ORDERS</li>
</ul>
```

I was hoping that if I used  `li[class*="secMenu_link"]` , anything beginning with `.secMenu_link` would be styled with those rules (ex: `.secMenu_link_active`) would inherit those rules AND any rules unique to `.secMenu_link_active`

This does not seem to be the case though. What Would `li[class*="secMenu_link"]` be doing, exactly? And, is there any way to achieve what I mentioned above?

Or to achieve that effect, do I have to do:

CSS

```
.generic, .generic_typeB {
    /* styles A */
}

.generic_typeB {
    /* styles B */
}
```

My intent in this example is to have `.generic_typeB` inherit from `.generic` and have its own rules, but I thought the syntax I discovered at the beginning of this post, may help me organize things in a different manner.

Thanks much for your time.

Comment: Attribute selectors aren't mean to be used that way, are you sure this is the best solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Using `li[class*="secMenu_link"]` in the CSS you provided does work exactly how CSS should.

CSS determines which elements receive which styles based on a system of specificity - that is, the more specific a selector the more likely it will take precedence.

Basically what is happening is that the rules in your `.activeLink` selector are applying, but are being overridden by the rules applied in `li[class*="secMenu_link"]` because it is the more specific selector.

You have two options here:

Change your selector to be more specific ([working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZFze/2/))

```
li[class*="secMenu_link"].activeLink {
    background:#f36459;
    border:2px solid #f36459;
    color:#444;
}
```

Or add an `!important` flag to the overridden rules in `.activeLink` ([working example](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZFze/1/))

```
.activeLink {
    background:#f36459 !important;
    border:2px solid #f36459 !important;
    color:#444 !important;
}
```

For more information on specificity, have a look at [this link](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/).